# Least bad way to manually show a tooltip in ApexCharts (for synchronising charts viewed in different sessions)

Tags: blazor, apexcharts

The problem: I have two ApexChart views of the same chart data, on different web pages.  I want to be able to hover or click from one view (the "presenter view"), and have the corresponding tooltips appear on the other view (the "public view").  Obviously the server backend needs to support this and manage communication between the views, but it's the browser-side part that I have no idea how to do.

To add to the complexity, I'm doing this using Blazor ApexCharts, and I'm new to both ApexCharts and Blazor.  To simplify matters, I'm just doing it in Blazor Hybrid to begin with, so it's all running on the one device.  I'm pretty sure I can't get what I want through the Blazor wrapper itself, so I expect to have to do some Javascript magic, but I don't know what's the most natural way to achieve this without fighting against ApexCharts.

What's working so far: Blazor ApexCharts exposes an OnDataPointEnter event when I hover over an item in the presenter view, from which I can update the viewmodel, which triggers an event that's received by the public view.  But I can't find any way of making the public view show the tooltip I want.

There's an ApexCharts method exposed called toggleDataPointSelection, which is also exposed by the Blazor wrapper, but that just de/highlights the data entry; it doesn't show the tooltip.

Manually searching through the child SVG elements, I can find the one whose j and index attributes match the indices of the data series and data point.  But trying to trigger mouseenter/hover/etc events on that element is doing nothing.  I'm not sure if this is because of security restrictions around faking pointer events, or if ApexCharts just doesn't listen to these ones.

Faking a mouse-move event over the entire chart is no good, because the two views will have different layouts and resolutions, meaning there's no simple mapping between coordinates on the two views, so this will have to be an event on the chart element corresponding to the specific datapoint in question.

Is there any reasonable way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.